# Can't figure out what a file is

Tags: files, osx

I have this file I just noticed in my home directory. I'm using OS X. Using ls -l, I get:

```
srwxr-xr-x    1 bryan  staff           0 Jul  7 11:33 {57A30B12-5DF8-467E-AA55-E502FEAC0B7A}
```

Trying cat {57A30B12-5DF8-467E-AA55-E502FEAC0B7A} returns

```
cat: {57A30B12-5DF8-467E-AA55-E502FEAC0B7A}: Connection refused
```

The permissions in particular confuses me. What does the s stand for?

Comment: You can also get information with `fuset filename` or with `sudo netstat -p | grep filename`, it should show you PIDs of processes using the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first character of `ls` being an `s` means this file is a *socket*.

It's a bit like a TCP socket, but for communication between a client and a server process on the same machine, using the filesystem /path/to/socket as the name, instead of a TCP port number.

You can read more about sockets with `man 2 socket`, but that does get a bit technical.

Comment: Any idea why it is there? What is using the socket?

Comment: I find the creation date odd too, as it's over a month ago.

Comment: What's the full path to the socket?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, should have mentioned it is in my home direction.

Comment: Then it could be almost anything; `$HOME/{some-uuid-value}` doesn't give a lot of information :-(  You might try `lsof | grep _the_uuid` to see if any process is still running and listening to it, but I don't hold out much hope.